# managing multiple contact sources as gmail contacts

Tags: contacts, sync, 4.2-jelly-bean, google-contacts

I'm on a google nexus 4 (up to date, non-rooted) and I'm using gmail and google contacts for my contact/messaging needs. Additionally I'm pulling contacts from facebook, linkedIn, xing (German linkedIn clone) and google plus.

Is there an easy way to merge contact info from other networks into the gmail contact when joining/linking contacts from gmail and other networks like facebook and linkedIn?

I wouldn't mind using a third party app to do the footwork (joining, unduping, etc.) but I'd like to keep and update the data in my gmail contact list as I am using this list half of the time on my desktop. I don't mind using another contacts app for viewing/browsing and calling/texting my contacts but I don't want to depend on one forever and I don't want to redo everything again and again everytime I switch my phone and/or contacts app

I know that Smartr and Rapportive (Desktop only) can do a lot of association stuff but in  the end all the data that happens in Smartr stays in Smartr.

Things I'd like to have:

1. Data

   1. Contact Name
   2. Picture (assigned by me, default g+ with facebook or linkedIn as fallback)
   3. Nickname
   4. basic gmail stuff, multiple numbers, mails, addresses, birthday, other dates, urls
   5. other network profiles as "profile URLs" or sound "other URLs"
2. Functionality

   1. easy linking/joining and un-duping
   2. data storage in gmail contacts as fas as possible
   3. compatibility with other apps like smartr or rapportive

Comment: The usual answer on that was (at least a while ago) using the GMail web interface. But with all those re-desings lately, I'm not sure if that feature does still exist, or whether it was replaced by some colorful "tile"...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm working primarily with the Gmail Web Interface since I'm a web dev and bound to my pc 9-5 + side projects. But everytime I start updating contacs I feel there are either fields or sometimes even entries missing...

Comment: Since their latest relaunch, I use those Google tools only when forced to. They're getting worse each day (at least that's my subjective feeling). But give me a few minutes, I just happened to remember an alternative solution which might work for you. Will place it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KADlancer - check out http://www.fullcontact.com. (Full disclosure: I work for them, so I'm a bit biased. But the issues you mentioned are exactly the issues we're trying to solve).

We currently have a web app in private beta that pulls in contacts from various Google Contacts/Gmail sources, as well as Facebook, Foursquare, LinkedIn, Twitter, etc. It then adds social profile data to each, normalizes & de-dupes them, and syncs them back in real-time.

Within the next month we plan to roll out our public beta, which will support the linking of all of the above sources - meaning you can unify contacts across all your social networks/Google accounts and have all your contacts in one place, automatically up-to-date. Because we offer two-way sync in real-time, changes made in Google Contacts sync to FullContact, and vice-versa - meaning that your data is your data, and stays where you want it (no walled gardens).

Again, I work for them, so you'd probably be right to take what I'm saying with a grain of salt. But based on what you posted, it looks like the FullContact Address Book will do almost everything you're looking to do (with the possible exception of Xing, which is currently not supported, but on the roadmap). I'm not aware of any other app out there that does quite what we do, save Smartr - which it sounds like you've already tried.

Good luck!

Comment: sounds amazing, any chance for me to get into the closed beta and give it a go? I'm willing to put hours of work into feedback mails / posts if your solution ends up exactly what I need for this special problem (which bugs me ever since getting my first smartphone).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't control that - I know they're pushing hard to get one universally-requested major feature finished before letting in any more beta users outright. But if you sign up for the wait list, they should be able to get you in within the next month. (& I *definitely* understand the "bugging me ever since my first smartphone" bit. I've been having the same issue as far back as my Handspring Treo. Ridiculous.)

Comment: Already signed on directly after reading your reply. Waiting and looking for some tea right now (sorry, reference to a German proverb). Looking forward to give FullContact a go.

Comment: after finally getting access to fullcontact, I have to say its definitely headed in the right direction. I'll give it a go for a while and report back as soon as I can tell if this is realy what I was looking for. Looking good so far!

Comment: Awesome! It's definitely in (open) beta, so any and all feedback is very much appreciated. We want to build a product that you love.

Answer (score 1):

As Google's web frontends get worse each day currently (there used to be a nice way to merge contact with GMail, but with the latest re-designs I'm not sure which features are still left in working order), you might wish to take a look at a few app-based solutions:

- [Contact Remover Plus](http://www.appbrain.com/app/contact-remover-plus/com.holyhog.dcfdpro): Other than the name might suggest, the Plus version also offers to merge contacts, copy contacts between accounts, and move contacts between accounts
- [Contrack](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Contrack-Personal-Networking/com.acquasys.contrack) mentions some "linking" stuff (but not much details)

The first one looks the most promising in your context. Not sure about Facebook etc. though, as I don't use those networks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I just had a look at both. Contrack seems to go into another direction with a heavy focus on checkins and interactions. The first one (Contact Remover Plus) looks interesting but after reading the developer's description and warning about syncing merged contacts to external services that might result in data loss I guess I chicken out and continue my search.

Comment: I'll upvote you as soon as I have enough reputation as your links are helpfull even though they are not a perfect match for my problem.

Comment: As you have already more than [15 rep](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up), feel free :) Glad I could help!